# Jquery Mobile anchor tag CSS issue on mobile devices

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, mobile, anchor

I'm currently working with JQuery Mobile and have come across a slight issue regarding CSS. Normally, given time I would be able to track down the issue and put it right but this time I thought I'd put it out there and see if anyone else has had this problem because I'm having no luck tracking down the right CSS to correct it.

The issue itself is only presenting itself on **mobile** testing. I have standard links on page

```
<a class="inline" data-ajax="false" href="/members/account">Account</a>
```

Pretty standard, however when you tap the link on a mobile device, a black border and some slight padding are present for a split second as you click the link. thus making the link position shift slightly, which doesn't look good. Normally I would assume that it would just be a case of disabling the border/outline (I can't be sure which) and padding in an `:active` style. But so far I've had no joy.

I would like to post a screenshot of whats happening to give you a better idea but because of when this issue occurs, its pretty impossible to do so. The links are fine on desktop, and also on a minimized desktop window to replicate mobile browsing, but not on the device itself.

My gut tells me that its to do with the `.ui-btn-inner` class. As JQuery mobile assigns automatic classes to different elements on page. But again I can't be 100% on this. If anyone has encountered this before, can you shed some light?

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Quick screenshot mockup outlining the problem

[image: Black border with annotation]

Comment: A small screencast would be cool instead of a screenshot.

Comment: @digitalextremist Whats the quickest way to do that?

Comment: On a Mac, use Quicktime screen record. On Windows, use Jing. On linux, no idea at the moment.

Comment: @digitalextremist Well the issue only displays on mobile browsers so making a screencast via desktop won't show the problem. I know, I appreciate that the problem is extremely vague. Just a black border/outline when link with `href=` is tapped on phone and tablet

Comment: my bad, forgot it's on mobile... android: https://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/

Comment: @digitalextremist Afraid not. iPhone 4s and iPad

Comment: http://rumorscity.com/2013/10/06/3-ways-to-record-screencast-on-your-iphone-or-ipad/

Comment: Have posted a mockup of the issue if that helps. the black border appears and then disappears, indicating an `:active` property surely. Just confusing why its mobile device specific

Answer (score 0):

OK, seem to have finally figured out the issue due to a lot of trial and error but got there in the end. Seemed to be a drop shadow on a JQuery specifc class of `ui-shadow`. So just needed to get rid of that.

Thanks anyway to @digitalextremist for your response.